# How does GitHub encode their graphQL cursors?

Tags: graphql, pagination, reverse-engineering

GitHub's graphql cursors are intentionally opaque, so they shouldn't ever be decode by a client. However I'd like to know their approach towards pagination, especially when combined with sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple layers of encoding for the encoding used for pagination cursors used by GitHub. I will list them in order from the perspective of a decoder:

1. The cursor string is encoded using [URL safe base64](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5) meaning it uses `-` and `_` instead of `+` and `/`. This might be to have consistency with their REST based API.
2. Decoding the base64 string gives us another string in the format of `cursor:v2:[something]` so the next step is decoding the something.
3. The 'something' is a binary encoded piece of data containing the actual cursor properties. The first byte defines the cursor type:

   - `0x91` => We don't use any sorting, the cursor contains the length of the id field and the id itself. `0xcd` seems to indicate a two-byte id, `0xce` a four-byte id. This is followed by the id itself, which can be verified by decoding the base64 `id` graphql field.
   - `0x92` => A composite cursor containing the sorted property and the id. This is either a length-prefixed ordinal number or two bytes plus a string or ISO date string followed by the length-prefixed id.

Comment: Hi, where is this documented? I remember that the cursor is indeed b64, but can't find that in the docs any more. Thanks!

Comment: @MinhNghĩa As far as I know this is not documented, cursors and ids are intentionally opaque. I "reverse engineered" how GitHub handles them, to better understand the concepts involved. You shouldn't actively decode the cursors/ids as their implementation is not guaranteed to remain the same.